# Resetting a script after game round?

Tags: lua, reset, roblox

When the game timer ends it kills the players & resets the teams and sends them to spawn to choose a Team again... idk how to reset the script to start from the beginning and have reset all the values and functions called... I tried making a copy of the script and destroy the current one with script:Destroy() but doesn't work & continues with the same function so breaks my game when the players choose the teams again & respawn.

```
-- Get Service Variables
local Teams = game:GetService("Teams")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local plr = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer

-- Wait for Child Variables
local TeamResetter = game.ReplicatedStorage.TeamResetter
local TimeCountdown = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Timer")


--Scripts Resets the entire script after GameTime is up
local function ResetGame(Player,Teams)
    local copy = script:Clone()
    copy.Parent = script.Parent
    script:Destroy()
end


-- Destroy Gate when thieves touch it
game.Workspace.CarGate4.GateRod.Touched:Connect(function(hit,Player)
    local h = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if h ~= nil then
        local n = hit.Parent
        local p = game.Players:FindFirstChild(n.Name)
        if p.Team.Name == "Thieves" then
            game.Workspace.CarGate4.GateRod:Destroy()
        end
    end         
end)


--Thieves function for winning
--[[humanoid.Seated:Connect(function(active,currentSeat, Player, Team)
    if active then
        if currentSeat.Name == "DriveSeat" then
            if Player.TeamColor == game.Teams.Thieves.TeamColor then
                game.StarterGui.ThiefWinScreen.Frame.TextLabel.Script.Disabled = false
        end

    end

end
end)]]


local function PoliceWinReset(Player,Team)
    game.StarterGui.PoliceWinScreen.Frame.TextLabel.Script.Disabled = false
    wait(2)
    for i,v in pairs(game.Teams.Thieves:GetPlayers()) do
        Player.TeamColor = game.Teams.ChoosingTeam.TeamColor
        game.StarterGui.ThiefWinScreen.Frame.TextLabel.KillPlayer.Disabled = false
        Player.Character:BreakJoints()
        game.StarterGui.ChooseTeamGUI.Enabled = true
        ResetGame(Player,Teams)
    end
    for i,v in pairs(game.Teams.Police:GetPlayers()) do
        Player.TeamColor = game.Teams.ChoosingTeam.TeamColor
        game.StarterGui.PoliceWinScreen.Frame.TextLabel.KillPlayer.Disabled = false
        Player.Character:BreakJoints()
        game.StarterGui.ChooseTeamGUI.Enabled = true
        ResetGame(Player,Teams)
end
end

--Starts Global timer for game after user chooses a team & Police win code
--Resets Player Teams and respawns them back at spawn and have to choose a team again
local function PlayGame(Player, Team)
    local timerAmount = 120
    local timerText = ""
    while timerAmount >= 0 do
        TimeCountdown:FireAllClients(timerAmount,timerText)
        wait(1)
        timerAmount -= 1
        if timerAmount == 0 then
            PoliceWinReset(Player,Team)
        end
    end
    return timerAmount
end
--Checks wether the user is on the Thieves or Police Teama
local function Thieves_Police(Player, Team)
    if Player.TeamColor == game.Teams.Police.TeamColor then
        game.StarterGui.ChooseTeamGUI.Enabled = false
        game.StarterGui.TimerGUI.Enabled = true
        wait(5)
        PlayGame(Player, Team)
        return Player, Team

    elseif Player.TeamColor == game.Teams.Thieves.TeamColor then
        game.StarterGui.ChooseTeamGUI.Enabled = false
        game.StarterGui.TimerGUI.Enabled = true
        wait(5)
        PlayGame(Player, Team)
        return Player, Team
    end
end
--Team Chooser
game.ReplicatedStorage.TeamChooser.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Player, Team)
    local PhysicalTeamColor = Teams:FindFirstChild(Team).TeamColor
    Player.TeamColor = PhysicalTeamColor
    game.StarterGui.PoliceWinScreen.Enabled = false
    game.StarterGui.ThiefWinScreen.Enabled = false
    Thieves_Police(Player, Team)
    
end)

--Gives the Users on the Police Team a Weapon on Spawn
function teamFromColor(color) 
    for _,t in pairs(game:GetService("Teams"):GetChildren()) do 
        if t.TeamColor==color then return t end 
    end 
    return nil 
end 


function onSpawned(plr) 
    local tools = teamFromColor(plr.TeamColor):GetChildren() 
    for _,c in pairs(tools) do 
        c:Clone().Parent = plr.Backpack 
    end 
end 

function onChanged(prop,plr) 
    if prop=="Character" then 
        onSpawned(plr) 
    end 
end 

function onAdded(plr) 
    plr.Changed:connect(function(prop) 
        onChanged(prop,plr) 
    end) 
end 



--Calls the Functions
game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(onAdded)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap the script in a `while loop` to repeat from the beginning when the round ends. At the end of the loop, right before the `end` tag, you can reset all the values that are supposed to be reset for the next round.